# Why doesn't my Docker Laravel (Sail) app show `.env` variables in web browser, but it does in Tinker?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have an .env variable in my Laravel application that is not being pulled from the file *only* when I'm trying to access the web app.

If I try to access config value from Tinker, (e.g., `config('clients.stripe.secretKey')`), the correct value shows up as expected in the command line.

If I try to use that config variable in the API client via web browser, I get an error saying that the configured key is set to the placeholder value copied over from `.env.example`.

Edit: Included error output, even though the error output literally tells you the exact same thing as what I stated in my above paragraph.

> Invalid API Key provided: test_str******cret

If I try to dump out the value using the above `config()` function inside of a controller (in the web browser) I also get the placeholder value from `.env.example`.

I have done the following with no success:

- `sail artisan config:clear`
- `sail artisan cache:clear`
- `sail composer dumpautoload`
- `sail composer update`
- checked tinker inside of the container itself through Docker, configs show up

Edit: Figured it out myself and accepted the answer. Just re-generate your application key.

Comment: Can you literally show us the error: "_I get an error saying that the configured key is set to the placeholder value_"

Comment: Your app is running in Sail (docker), so how would it be accessible from outside the container? Also what is the literal error you talked about.

Comment: Actual error messaged added. Not quite sure what the point of your first question is, @geertjanknapen, seeing as how it's rhetorical in nature. If you'd like to reframe that into an actual question I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: Is that the full docker-compose file, if not show the full file.

Comment: You might want to show the relevant piece of your config file: `config('clients.client_name.key'))`, when you have an error, show your entire stack trace to that error. Your problem can be as simple as putting quotes around your API key in your .env file

Comment: @UnderDog thanks for the suggestion! I will do that immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I ended up running

`sail artisan optimize:clear`

followed by

`sail artisan key:generate`